# grep find letters between two spaces

Tags: bash

I have to find words.

In my assignment a word is defined as letters between two spaces (" bla "). I have to find a decimalIntegerConstant like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m22FA.png) but it has to be a word.

I use

```
 grep -E -o " (0|[1-9]+[0-9]*)([Ll]?) "
```

but it doesn't work on, for example:

> bla 0l labl 2 3 abla0La 0L sfdgpočítačsd

Output is

```
0l
2 
0L
```

but `3` is missing.

Comment: You are consuming the space when you match `2`. Try `grep -oP " (0|[1-9]+[0-9]*)[Ll]?(?= )"`

Comment: @123 In order to take beggining/end of lines into account and to remove spaces from the output, you could improve your regex like so : `grep -oP "(^| )\K((0|[1-9]+[0-9]*)[Ll]?)(?= |$)"`

Comment: @Aserre I purposefully didn't over complicate it as OP defined words as between two spaces but yes you could.

Comment: I use  `grep -E -o "\b(0|[1-9]+[0-9]*)([Ll]?)\b"`. Someone write it here but then delete post. Also your solutions work, but i don't understand them, so i rather use `\b` if it is ok.

Comment: `\b` is a word boundary, which includes spaces but also punctuation and line ends. So it will match all numbers in lines like `1,2,3`.

Comment: `grep -oP " (0|[1-9]+[0-9]*)[Ll]?(?= )"` this combined with `\K` is ok. I dont need `grep -oP "(^| )\K((0|[1-9]+[0-9]*)[Ll]?)(?= |$)"` because it has to be letters between two spaces (ASCII32). Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matches don't overlap. Your regex have matched `2`. The blank after `2` is gone. It won't be considered for further matches.

POSIX `grep` cannot do what you want in one step, but you can do something like this in two stages (simplified from your regex, doesn't support `[lL]`)

```
grep -o ' [0-9 ]* ' | grep -E -o '[0-9]+'
```

That is, match a sequence of space-separated numbers with leading and trailing spaces, and from that, match individual numbers regardless of spaces. De-simplify the definition of number to suit your needs.

Perl-compatible regular expressions have a way to match stuff without consuming it, for example, as mentioned in the comments:

```
grep -oP " (0|[1-9]+[0-9]*)[Ll]?(?= )"
```

`(?= )` is a *lookahead assertion*, which means `grep` will look ahead in the input stream and make sure the match is followed by a space. The space will not be considered a part of the match and will not be consumed. When no space is found, the match fails.

PCRE are not guaranteed to work in all implementations of `grep`.

Edit: `-o` is not specified by Posix either.

Comment: Doesn't provide an answer, that code will not work for OP's data

Comment: @123 answer is not necessarily defined as "code that works out of the box" but rather "useful information that helps to arrive to a solution". Having said that, feel free to downvote/flag if you think the answer is bad.

Comment: It won't work at all as is. `+` is not BRE. and posix grep doesn't support `-o`

Comment: @123 you are right, I missed -E, will add. Didn't know about -o being not posix though.